# Trying to learn boost::intrusive Q2

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, intrusive-containers

if I uncomment these

```
//BaseList   baselist; 
//MemberList memberlist;
```

outside the loop and comment out the ones inside the loop it crashes. I need to be able to have the baselist (and memberlist) outside any loop. How is this achieved?

**Edit**

> The actual problem I am trying to solve in it's simplest form is this.
>
> I want to have a std::vector of `MyClass`, call it AllThingsBunchedTogether. 
>   I also want to have a std::vector of `BaseList`, call it AllThingsSpreadOut.
>
> So
>
> - AllThingsBunchedTogether might contain (just the `anInt1` part for the sake of compactness): `1,2,1,10,2,3,4,4,5,9,10,10`.
> - AllThingsSpreadOut might contain (zero not used for now) at [1] `1,1` at [2] `2,2` at [3] `3` at [4] `4,4` at [5] `5` at [9] `9` at [10] `10,10,10`.
>
> Note that the numbers themselves aren't be stored in the `BaseList`, but e.g., the `MyClass`(1, "John").
>
> At [1] it could be "Mike", "John", at [2] it could be "Mike", "Dagobart" at [3]
>   "John" ... at [10] "John" "Mike" "Dagobart" etc so that there no duplicates in
>   any of the `BaseList` at AllThingsSpreadOut[i] since each `MyClass` in each
>   `BaseList` hashes to a different value (`anInt1 + Name`).
>
> In essence, `anInt1` tells where the `MyClass` lives in AllThingsSpreadOut, but `anInt1 + name` guarantees uniqueness within each `BaseList`.
>
> So the idea is that AllThingsSpreadOut is a vector of `BaseList` where at each `BaseList` at vector location is a list of similar things.
>
> Then, when I remove things from AllThingsBunchedTogether (not by a clear, but by a search to remove some items like in the code below IsMarkedToDelete), they will automatically disappear from the corresponding AllThingsSpreadOut.
>
> AllThingsSpreadOut acts as a sort for AllThingsBunchedTogether, with intrusive semantics. AllThingsBunchedTogether allows superfast access through [].

**End Edit**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/intrusive/list.hpp>

using namespace boost::intrusive;

class MyClass : public list_base_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>> // This is a derivation hook
{
public:
    std::string name;
    bool bIsMarkedToDelete;
    int anInt1;
public:
    list_member_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>> member_hook_; // This is a member hook

    MyClass(std::string n, int i) : name(n), anInt1(i), bIsMarkedToDelete(false) {}
};

bool IsMarkedToDelete(const MyClass &o)
{
    return o.bIsMarkedToDelete;
}

//Define a list that will store MyClass using the public base hook
typedef list<MyClass, constant_time_size<false>> BaseList;

// Define a list that will store MyClass using the public member hook
typedef list<MyClass,
        member_hook<MyClass, list_member_hook<link_mode<auto_unlink>>, &MyClass::member_hook_>,
        constant_time_size<false> > MemberList;

int main()
{
    bool done = false;
    std::vector<MyClass> values;

    std::string names[] = {"John", "Mike", "Dagobart"};

    //BaseList   baselist; 
    //MemberList memberlist;

    int i = 0;
    while(!done)
    {
        // Create several MyClass objects, each one with a different value

        for (int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
            values.emplace_back(names[j % 3], j);

        BaseList   baselist;
        MemberList memberlist;

        // Now insert them in t-he reverse order in the base hook list
        for (auto& e : values)
        {
            baselist.push_front(e);
            memberlist.push_back(e);
        }

        // Now test lists
        auto rbit(baselist.rbegin());
        auto mit(memberlist.begin());
        auto it(values.begin()), itend(values.end());

        // Test the objects inserted in the base hook list
        for (; it != itend; ++it, ++rbit)
        {
            if (&*rbit != &*it)
                return 1;
        }
        // Test the objects inserted in the member hook list
        for (it = values.begin(); it != itend; ++it, ++mit)
        {
            if (&*mit != &*it)
                return 1;
        }
# if 0
        for(auto& e : values)
            std::cout << e.anInt1 << "\n";

        for(auto& e : baselist)
            std::cout << e.anInt1 << "\n";

        for(auto& e : memberlist)
            std::cout << e.anInt1 << "\n";

#endif // 0

        if(2 == i)
        {
            for(auto& e: values)
                std::cout << e.name << "\n";

            for(auto& e: values)
            {
                if("Mike" == e.name)
                    e.bIsMarkedToDelete = true;
            }

            values.erase(
                std::remove_if(values.begin(), values.end(), IsMarkedToDelete), values.end());
        }


        if(i++ > 3)
        {
            values.clear();
            done = true;
        }

        std::cout << "\n";
        std::cout << values.size()     << "\n";
        std::cout << baselist.size()   << "\n";
        std::cout << memberlist.size() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to figure out what it is you wanted to achieve here. I can see no "solution" that makes sense given the sample code. Can you tell us what you want to achieve (outside artificial goals like "I need to be able to have the baselist (and memberlist) outside any loop")

Comment: sehe, the actual problem I am trying to solve is so much more complex than this that I have to think about how to ask it in a simple manner. Give me a little time to rephrase it.

Comment: Cheers. The thinking is always the solution ("How to solve a problem by almost asking about it on Stackoverflow")

Comment: See the Edit above. Hope that makes sense. Believe me I have fought with this problem for several days. I feel stupid, but I know that it is my unfamiliarity with Intrusive that is the problem. Do you see now why I can't just have the Baselist inside a loop?

Comment: I am honing in on the problem. The issue may be that I am using objects instead of pointers to objects...

Comment: thanks for the update. I'm still not completely convinced how the sample code matches the problem description (partly it does). Do you mind if I edit it a bit for clarity?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've seen it late, but anyways, here goes:

1. What you describe matches *exactly* the implementation of an intrusive hash table of `MyClass` elements, where

   - `anInt1` is the hash (the *bucket* identifier) for an element
   - the bucket lists are implemented as linked lists
   - equality is defined as equality of `(anInt1, Name)`

     > [image]

   So really, your program could *just* be:

   **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9eb4c7197c428ca)</kbd>**

   ```
   std::unordered_set<MyClass> values {
       { "John",      0 }, { "Mike",      1 }, { "Dagobart",  2 },
       { "John",      3 }, { "Mike",      4 }, { "Dagobart",  5 },
       { "John",      6 }, { "Mike",      7 }, { "Dagobart",  8 },
       { "John",      9 }, { "Mike",     10 },
   };

   for(int i = 0; i<=3; ++i) {
       if(2 == i) {
           for(auto& e: values) std::cout << e.name << " "; std::cout << "\n";
           for(auto& e: values) e.bIsMarkedToDelete |= ("Mike" == e.name);

           for(auto it=begin(values); it!=end(values);) {
               if (it->bIsMarkedToDelete) it = values.erase(it);
               else ++it;
           }
       }

       std::cout << "i=" << i << ", values.size(): " << values.size() << "\n";
   }
   values.clear();
   std::cout << "Done\n";
   ```
2. if you really wanted contiguous storage, I can only assume you wanted this for performance

   - you **do not** want to use pointers instead of objects, since that simply negates the memory layout ("AllThingsBunchedTogether") benefits and you'd be better of with the `unordered_set` or `unodered_map` as above
   - you **do not** want to use `auto_unlink` mode, since it cripples performance (by doing uncontrolled deletion triggers, by inhibiting constant-time `size()` and by creating thread safety issues)
   - instead, you should employ the above stratagy, but with `boost::intrusive::unordered_set` instead see http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/intrusive/unordered_set_unordered_multiset.html

     Here, again, is a proof-of-concept:

     **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/01d1f4905134bc0d)</kbd>**

     ```
     #include <vector>
     #include <iostream>
     #include <boost/intrusive/unordered_set.hpp>
     #include <vector>
     //#include <functional>
     //#include <algorithm>

     namespace bic = boost::intrusive;

     struct MyClass : bic::unordered_set_base_hook<bic::link_mode<bic::auto_unlink>>
     {
         std::string name;
         int anInt1;
         mutable bool bIsMarkedToDelete;

         MyClass(std::string name, int i) : name(name), anInt1(i), bIsMarkedToDelete(false) {}

         bool operator==(MyClass const& o) const { return anInt1 == o.anInt1 && name == o.name; }

         struct hasher { size_t operator()(MyClass const& o) const { return o.anInt1; } };
     };

     typedef bic::unordered_set<MyClass, bic::hash<MyClass::hasher>, bic::constant_time_size<false> > HashTable;

     int main() {

         std::vector<MyClass> values {
             MyClass { "John", 0 }, MyClass { "Mike",  1 }, MyClass { "Dagobart", 2 },
             MyClass { "John", 3 }, MyClass { "Mike",  4 }, MyClass { "Dagobart", 5 },
             MyClass { "John", 6 }, MyClass { "Mike",  7 }, MyClass { "Dagobart", 8 },
             MyClass { "John", 9 }, MyClass { "Mike", 10 },
         }; 

         HashTable::bucket_type buckets[100];
         HashTable hashtable(values.begin(), values.end(), HashTable::bucket_traits(buckets, 100)); 

         for(int i = 0; i<=3; ++i) {
             if(2 == i) {
                 for(auto& e: values) std::cout << e.name << " "; std::cout << "\n";
                 for(auto& e: values) e.bIsMarkedToDelete |= ("Mike" == e.name);

                 values.erase(std::remove_if(begin(values), end(values), std::mem_fn(&MyClass::bIsMarkedToDelete)));
             }

             std::cout << "i=" << i << ", values.size():    " << values.size()    << "\n";
             std::cout << "i=" << i << ", hashtable.size(): " << hashtable.size() << "\n";
         }
         values.clear();
         std::cout << "Done\n";
     }
     ```

Comment: Added coliru samples of both the standard hash-table as well as the Boost Intrusive version (still with `auto_unlink` mode nodes although I think already said I think it's not what you want)

Comment: sehe, your responses are never too late in my view. I learn a ton from your responses. Please feel free to educate. Thanks again.

Comment: BTW sehe, I am going to do a performance comparison of your initial suggestion (which I implemented and __is__ fast) and this new idea.

Comment: Does this __require__ boost_1_57 or later?

Comment: Nope. I compiled with 1_56

Answer (score 0):

Here's the error message, which you omitted:

```
Assertion `node_algorithms::inited(to_insert)' failed.
```

From this we can understand that an element is being inserted twice.  This isn't valid with intrusive containers in general.

When you have your lists inside the loop, they are destroyed and recreated each time.  But when they are outside, you never clear them, and you also never clear `values`, so this sequence occurs:

1. Add 11 elements to `values`.
2. Add all `values` to the lists.
3. Add 11 elements to `values`; it still has the previous 11 so now 22 elements.
4. Add all `values` to the lists.  Crash on the first one, because it is already in a list.

One solution is to add `values.clear()` at the top of the `while(!done)` loop.

Comment: The point is that if that's okay, then he wouldn't "require" the baseList/memberList outside the loop either. Clearing the vector (obviously) necessarily clears the list too (and if they weren't using `auto_unlink` hooks, it would just leave them dangling)

Comment: I solved it. I needed to use pointers. Thanks John and Sehe. Now I need to figure out how to do unit tests on these things.

Comment: Also, I forgot that erase invalidates iterators.

Comment: @Ivan in case you are still interested, I just saw your edit and treated it in an answer.